# jQuery submit button event handler prevents form validation for required input fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, submit-button

I have a HTML form with input fields which are required, for example:

```
<input type="number" required="required" />
```

The submit button of my form is controlled by a jQuery event handler:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(event){
  return false;
});
```

The fact that the submit button handler returns **false** leads to the problem that there is no automatic check for the required fields by the web browser. If I remove "return false" then there is a check *(see screenshot)* but then the page gets reloaded (which I don't want).

Is there a way, to use the browser's error correction without a page refresh after a form submit action?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try something like:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(event){
    return $("<some selector for the input>")[0].checkValidity();
});
```